# Facebook OAuth login problem with Facebook SDK 2.0

Tags: iphone, facebook, authentication, oauth, sdk

I am developing an iPhone application that deals with Facebook. I am using the latest SDK facebook-facebook-ios-sdk-cf1c2c3 (SDK 2.0) to allow the user to login to Facebook account using OAuth.

User can login without any problem in device iPod Touch(4.3.1). But in iPhone 3GS I get the following error:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be \u201cm.facebook.com\u201d which could put your confidential information at risk." UserInfo=0x1b8350 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?type=user_agent&display=touch&redirect_uri=fbconnect://success&sdk=2&scope=read_stream,publish_stream&client_id=<APP_ID>, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?type=user_agent&display=touch&redirect_uri=fbconnect://success&sdk=2&scope=read_stream,publish_stream&client_id=<APP_ID>, NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be \u201cm.facebook.com\u201d which could put your confidential information at risk., NSUnderlyingError=0x1b83a0 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be \u201cm.facebook.com\u201d which could put your confidential information at risk.", NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=<SecTrustRef: 0x1be310>}
```

I extracted the URL from the FBLoginDailog and tried loading it in iPhone -> Safari. It redirects to the following URL and allows the user to login:

```
http://m.facebook.com/login.php?app_id=<APP_ID>&sdk=2&cancel=fbconnect://success?error_reason=user_denied&error=access_denied&error_description=The+user+denied+your+request.&fbconnect=1&next=https://www.facebook.com/connect/uiserver.php?method=permissions.request&app_id=<APP_ID>&display=touch&redirect_uri=fbconnect;//success&sdk=2&type=user_agent&fbconnect=1&perms=read_stream,publish_stream&from_login=1&rcount=1
```

Also, I have find the following workaround from the link:
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/issues/139

But, the link also mentions not to use it for App Store executable. But, I am getting the problem for app store executable also.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was not SDK problem. The date and time set in Device (3GS) was improper.

Comment: thanks for the answer!  I was actually trying to figure out why my friend's iPhone 3G would not log in to facebook.  It produced this 1202 error.  Googling didn't help, but stackoverflow did!  thanks! +1